# When to sharp-quote a lambda expression?

Tags: elisp, functions

**Q:** When, if ever, is it useful to sharp-quote a `lambda`, and when, if ever, must we *not* sharp-quote a `lambda`?

People use `lambda`s in three ways:

1. plain: `(lambda (x) x)`
2. quoted: `'(lambda (x) x)`
3. sharp-quoted: `#'(lambda (x) x)`

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852844/emacs-lisp-difference-between-function-lambda-and-lambda) discusses the three types, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948325/why-not-quoting-lambda) explains why not to quote (NB: not *sharp-quote*) `lambda`s, and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801396/when-should-emacs-function-syntax-be-used) also discusses the distinctions between quoting and sharp-quoting.

Now, the [manual node on anonymous functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) and the docstring for `lambda` note that `lambda`s are self-quoting:

> A call of the form `(lambda ARGS DOCSTRING INTERACTIVE BODY)` is
>   self-quoting; the result of evaluating the lambda expression is the
>   expression itself.  The lambda expression may then be treated as a
>   function...

So, it appears that `(lambda (x) x)` and `#'(lambda (x) x)` are equivalent, but `'(lambda (x) x)` is not (most importantly, when byte-compiling).

It looks like one would rarely want to *quote* a `lambda`, but it's unclear to me when, if ever, we should, or should not, sharp-quote:

- Is sharp-quoting a `lambda` simply a stylistic choice, or are there circumstances in which sharp-quoting is actually useful?
- Are there circumstances in which we must *not* sharp-quote a `lambda`, that is, when doing so would alter the meaning of the code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Once upon a time](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html), the sharp quote was necessary for lambdas, now that's no longer the case.

> So, it appears that (lambda (x) x) and #'(lambda (x) x) are equivalent, but '(lambda (x) x) is not (most importantly, when byte-compiling).

Yes. In fact, the first two are completely identical when evaluated. As described in the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) you linked:

> The following forms are all equivalent:
>
> ```
> (lambda (x) (* x x)) 
> (function (lambda (x) (* x x))) 
> #'(lambda (x) (* x x))
> ```

Other than trying to support Emacs versions from two decades ago, there's never a reason to sharp quote a lambda.

**So don't.**

---

As a sidenote:

- Hard quoting a lambda (with `'`) does make a difference, it prevents byte compilation. I can't think of a scenario where that's useful, but who knows.
- The backtic is the only quote that's genuinely useful with lambdas, but only if you're not using lexical binding for some reason.

Comment: Consider adding a link to the [Anonymous Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) section of the manual which contains an example explaining the effect of quoting on byte compilation.

Comment: @Constantine Done. I got lazy cause I'm on a phone, and the OP already linked it anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about not using lexical binding and backtick? Thanks.

Comment: @coredump With dynamic binding, the only way to make outside variables accessible inside a lambda is to manually build the lambda as a list with the variable inside. Backtics are good for that kind of thing.

Comment: BTW, I don't think "once upon a time" really applies: when I investigated this subject in the revision history, I found that `lambda` has been defined as a macro which adds the `function` for as back as I could go.  IOW if `#'` has been needed at some point, it was in *very* early development code.  It sure was not needed already in Emacs-18.

Comment: @Stefan Curious. I'm sure I didn't make that up though. I must have read that somewhere, or at least something that made we reach that conclusion. I guess that's what I get for not linking my sources. :-(

Comment: In fact, I *must* have done some form of investigating, because I explicitly say "over 2 decades ago" in this blog post: http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html

Comment: Maybe it was a combination of 2 things. (1) I've seen a lot of old Emacs code where lambdas are quoted with `'` or `#'`, it could just be bad code, but it probably led me to conclude that quoting used to be necessary. (2) I tried to track down when `lambda` was first defined as a macro and reached the commit `ffd56f97cf56501f7a6981c184192e9043e4eafd`, which was "a little over 2 decades ago".

Comment: Hmm.... indeed it appears you're right: it was added by Jim Blandy in May 1992 in the commit you cite and I can't find a `lambda` macro in Emacs-18.59, so apparently it was introduced in Emacs-19.

Answer (score 5):

Since `lambda` doesn't make any sense when it's not quoted, recent versions of Emacs Lisp follow (ANSI) Common Lisp in interpreting unquoted `(lambda...)` as `#'(lambda...)`.  The two notations are almost exactly equivalent (except within quoted structure).

Whether to prefer `(lambda...)` or `#'(lambda...)` is therefore purely a matter of style.  Some people prefer the naked form, which avoids syntactic noise, while others (including myself) prefer the quoted form.

Comment: This contradicts the elisp manual: "In Emacs Lisp, such a list is a valid expression which evaluates to a function object."

Comment: "Recent versions" as in "versions released after 1990 or so" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit of additional history, on account of seeing [Is #'(lambda ...) historical legacy?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46818)

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=4290 suggests that:

> Starting with Emacs 22, a `lambda` form is byte-compiled when it is used
>   as a function, regardless of whether it is preceded by `function` or
>   `#'`.  With Emacs versions prior to 22, you must explicitly use `#'`
>   or `function` if you want the form to be byte-compiled.

I don't know about the byte-compiler, but I can see that at least as far back as 1993 the `lambda` macro itself returned a `(function (lambda ...))` form.

https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~monnier/hopl-4-emacs-lisp.pdf also says:

> Interestingly (unlike MacLisp), `lambda` was not technically part of the Elisp language until around 1991 when it was added as a macro, early during the development of Emacs-19.  In Emacs-18, anonymous functions were written as quoted values of the form:
>
> ```
> '(lambda (..ARGS..) ..BODY..)
> ```
>
> While the `lambda` macro has made this quote unnecessary for almost 30 years now, many instances of this practice still occur in Elisp code, even though it prevents byte-compilation of the body.  Somewhat relatedly, only in 1993 did Lucid Emacs 19.8 import the `#'...` reader shorthand for `(function ...)` from MacLisp.  Emacs followed suit the year after.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give an practical example of using backtic lambda expression. It's about lexical-binding / variable shadowing, using a backtic lambda expression and referencing variables with a comma makes it possible to get their global value.

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(let ((my-variable "Random old"))
  (funcall `(lambda()
             (let ((my-variable "Random"))
               (message ,my-variable)))))
```

`M-x [RET] eval-buffer` outputs "Random old"

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(let ((my-variable "Random old"))
  (funcall (lambda()
             (let ((my-variable "Random"))
               (message my-variable)))))
```

`M-x [RET] eval-buffer` outputs "Random"

A third example combining global variable and local variable of variable

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(let ((my-variable "Random old"))
  (funcall `(lambda()
              (let ((my-variable "Random"))
                (message my-variable)
                (message ,my-variable)))))
```

`M-x [RET] eval-buffer` outputs "Random" "Random old"

Comment: @npostavs that was not the point with my example but I modified my example to avoid that bad practice as well

Comment: Better, though I'm still not convinced this is an improvement over just choosing a different name for the inner binding.