# yasnippet configuration does not persist across emacs runs

Tags: completion, yasnippet

yasnippet does not complete snippets that I add to `yas/root-directory` (typing the key and hitting tab does not complete).

If I remove `.yas-compiled-snippets.el` from an affected directory, then run `yas/recompile-all` then `yas/reload-all`, I can temporarily use the snippets in that directory.  This works for one emacs session, but when I start emacs again, yasnippet again does not recognize the extra snippets.

How can I make the configuration "stick" across runs of emacs?

My yasnippet configuration is like this:

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas/initialize)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                               (yas-minor-mode)))
(add-to-list 'yas/root-directory "/path/to/elisp/yasnippet-snippets/")
(add-to-list 'yas/root-directory "/path/to/elisp/yasnippet-extra-snippets/")
```

Comment: The doc-string for `yas-snippet-dirs` *may* answer your question.  `M-x describe-variable RET yas-snippet-dirs RET`.  The variable name `yas/root-directory` is a backwards-compatible alias.  "*Directory or list of snippet dirs for each major mode. The directory where user-created snippets are to be stored. Can also be a list of directories. In that case, when used for bulk (re)loading of snippets (at startup or via 'yas-reload-all'), directories appearing earlier in the list shadow other dir's snippets. Also, the first directory is taken as the default for storing the user's new snippets.*"

Comment: @lawlist That doesn't seem to point to a problem in my case: my own snippet directories appear first on `yas-snippet-dirs` (and also the snippet I tested with has a key that is not used in the snippets that come with yasnippet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yas-reload-all` is the correct way to tell yasnippet about updates to `yas-snippet-dirs` (aka `yas/root-directory`), recompilation is not needed.

`yas/initialize` is basically an obsolete way of saying `(yas-global-mode +1)`, hence your `python-mode-hook` is redundant. `yas-global-mode` also calls `yas-reload-all` when it's turned on, so if you just set `yas-snippet-dirs` *before* calling it, your snippets will already be picked up:

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "/path/to/elisp/yasnippet-snippets/")
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "/path/to/elisp/yasnippet-extra-snippets/")
(yas-global-mode +1)
```

Or, enabling yasnippet only in `python-mode`:

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "/path/to/elisp/yasnippet-snippets/")
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "/path/to/elisp/yasnippet-extra-snippets/")
(yas-reload-all)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually don't really want yasnippet elsewhere than `python-mode` at the moment, so I added `(yas-reload-all)` to my hook (and removed the `yas/initialize`)

Comment: @CroadLangshan: reloading in the hook is overkill, since it runs every time you open a new python file. I added an example for enabling yasnippet only in `python-mode`.

Comment: Oops, very lazy of me.  And ditto re eliminating the lambda.  Out of curiosity: are you using the `#` there just as a coding style convention because sometimes it's useful as documentation to make it clear that it's a function?  Seems it can be omitted here...

Comment: yes, `#'` vs `'` in this case is just style, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16802304/319698 and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5364/5296

Comment: I'm running emacs 25, so I might have run into something deprecated, but for me the add-hook line should read `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode)`

Comment: @Silfheed: no, you're correct, I just made a mistake, it's fixed now.

Comment: “...so if you just set yas-snippet-dirs *before* calling it, your snippets will already be picked up”. The **before** part was what I was missing.