# Yasnippet - No snippet tables active/ YASnippet tables empty

Tags: yasnippet

In `.emacs`, I bound the key for `yasnippet` as,

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-SPC") 'yas-expand)
```

In a buffer with `python` as major mode and `yasnippet, autocomplete` as minor mode, `yasnippet` doesn't expand on `C-SPC`.

Now, i started doubting if there are any snippets available. I did `C-c & C-v` (or) `Visit Snippet File` and it gives alarm, `No snippet tables active`.

How to add snippets to a major mode?

Comment: Have a look at "The Condition System" over here: http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html Is that maybe what you need?

Comment: Using "C-SPC" works for me. Did you try expanding other snippets? Maybe type "fd" and see if it expands to a function with a docstring.
I think a "class" snippet just doesn't exist, I think it's "cls" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, `yas-snippets` doesn't get loaded by default. Calling `yas-reload-all` loaded the python snippets. I confirmed, the snippets are loaded by listing them with `C-c & C-v`. And it works now...

Comment: That's true if you aren't using `yas-global-mode`, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10531/5296

Comment: yes, i used `M-x yas-minor-mode` inside the buffer...