# What is the difference between ' and #' in front of a symbol?

Tags: elisp, hooks, functions, quote

I'm a little new to Emacs.
When looking at some of the configurations, I found there are two types command in "add-hook".

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'LaTeX-math-mode)
```

and

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
```

This has confused me for a long time and I don't know how to search "#'" in google...

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701698/emacs-elisp-what-is-the-hash-pound-number-sign-octothorp-symbol-used-for

Comment: See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSymbolNotation

Comment: Duplicates on other sites are fine. There's one here, though, which is *almost* a duplicate. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3595/50

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp, if `foo` is a symbol, then `'foo` and `#'foo` are completely equivalent.  The latter form (with `#'`) is preferred when `foo` is a function, as it documents the fact that it is intended to be funcalled.

Your two forms are therefore completely equivalent, and the one with `#'` is preferred.

**Edit**: as pointed out by Malabarba, this is not quite true: `#'` on symbols will cause the byte-compiler to emit a warning if the function is not defined.

(Note that this is not the case for lambda-forms, for which plain `'` prevents the byte-compiler from compiling the lambda-form, as [documented elsewhere](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/when-to-sharp-quote-a-lambda-expression).  Note further that this is also not necessarily the case in other Lisp dialects, for example in Common Lisp `#'foo` performs early binding.)