# Yasnippet with CEDET

Tags: yasnippet, cedet, config

I used to launch yasnippet just with c-mode with a hook in my .emacs but after adding some code to use CEDET and ECB yasnippet doesn't run automatically. I guess some modes may have been overwritten by CEDET, so how do I launch yasnippet mode automatically on c-mode now ?

```
(yas-reload-all)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
                     (#'yas-minor-mode)))
(global-ede-mode 1)  ; Enable the Project   management system                                        
(semantic-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)
(require 'semantic/sb)
```

I haven't understood the full CEDET configuration process so I may have done something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Your `add-hook` looks wrong, shoud be just `(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode)`

Comment: It works !
I've read that proper way to do hooks was to give them a lamba function. But that doesn't make sense. I still don't understand what the # is for...
Thank you !

Comment: Only if you needed to pass arguments to the function then you would need to wrap it in a lambda (although I would prefer using `defun`). Regarding `#'`, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10938/5296