# Where is cl-constantly and what to use instead?

Tags: cl-lib

In Common Lisp, there is
[`constantly`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm)
function, which creates new function without side-effects that takes any
number of arguments and always returns specified value.

For some reason `cl-lib` doesn't provide `cl-constantly`, so I guess it
should exist in pure Emacs Lisp under different name. Do you know that name?

---

Please don't post answers showing how to achieve effect of `constantly` manually (and how to define such function), since it's absolutely trivial. This question about name of already existing function. If there is no such function, a comment about the fact will do. I've sent a bug report asking to add the function.

Comment: dash calls it [`-const-c`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-const-c)

Comment: @npostavs, this is something you can post as an answer actually, since `dash.sh` is a popular library.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `constantly` equivalent in Emacs (except `ignore` is like `(constantly nil)`), but dash provides one called [`-const`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-const-c) as part of the `dash-functional` package.

> #### -const `(c)`
>
> Return a function that returns `c` ignoring any additional arguments.
>
> In types: a -> b -> a
>
> ```el
> (funcall (-const 2) 1 3 "foo") ;; => 2
> (-map (-const 1) '("a" "b" "c" "d")) ;; => '(1 1 1 1) 
> (-sum (-map (-const 1) '("a" "b" "c" "d"))) ;; => 4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined Emacs-Lisp function for this, as far as I know.

Here is a definition - the same as is shown in the [Common Lisp standard](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cons_1.htm):

```el
(defun constantly (object)
  (lambda (&rest arguments) object))
```

You need to have `lexical-binding` turned on (non-`nil`) for that definition. If you have it turned off (`nil`) then you can use this definition instead:

```el
(defun constantly (object)
  `(lambda (&rest arguments) ',object))
```

Comment: So, why there is no `cl-constantly` then?

Comment: Emacs Lisp does not attempt to emulate all of Common Lisp. Ask `emacs-devel@gnu.org` or `M-x report-emacs-bug`, if you want to request that some Common-Lisp feature be added.

Comment: As far as quoting the lambda is concerned, please see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3598/2223 .

Comment: @jch, I think that should go in the comments to other answer, but of course you can type extra `#'` every time without any benefit increasing visual noise. In additional to my previous comment `constantly` is a conceptual tool and part of vocabulary, it does not matter what is shorter, `constantly` is embodiment of a certain idea. I can imagine if there were no such thing as `identity` you would say that `(lambda (x) x)` will do.

Comment: @jch: That lambda form is **not** quoted (and believe me, I'm well aware of the question of quoting lambdas). It is **backquoted**. And for a reason: the resulting function has no free variable, `object`. The **value** of `object` at the time function `constantly` is called is substituted for the variable itself. And yes, this means that the function is a *list*: a lambda form, and does not get compiled, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually avoid the use of `constantly` by writing the equivalent lambda-term inline.  For example, in Common Lisp you could generate a list of 42s of the same length as a given list with

```
(mapcar (constantly 42) '(1 2 3))
```

In Emacs Lisp, you can do just the same with an explicit lambda-term:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (_) 42) '(1 2 3))
```

Barely longer, and much clearer in my opinion.

Comment: Well, you can do the same in Common Lisp without any problems. And by the way you don't need to quote lambda form since `lambda` is already a macro in modern lisps that expands exactly to `#'(lambda (...) ...)`. Please don't show me how to do it manually, since it's trivial. This question about name of already existing function. If there is no such function, a comment about the fact will do. I've already sent a bug report asking to add `cl-constantly`.

Comment: Also you solution is not the same as `constantly`, since real `constantly` can take any number of arguments.