# What is the difference between #'fun and 'fun?

Tags: elisp

In [this configuration file](https://github.com/Schnouki/dotfiles/blob/1e8b6cfa7cd98e28b5ad38f2988f4c0b5db3c178/emacs/init-20-tex.el), I've discovered the `#'` operator, which I did not know, used as:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)
```

I'm wondering what is the difference with writing just

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

The [only documentation I could find about this `#'` operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) hints that it may have some effect when the code is byte-compiled, but I don't understand how.  Is there any difference in this case?  If yes, how can I observe it?

Comment: Related reading: [When to sharp-quote a lambda expression?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/when-to-sharp-quote-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: @Dan The first link in the answer to that related question (http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html) might actually be the answer to mine: `#'foo` would give an error at compilation if `foo` is not the name of a function.