# Run flyspell-buffer automatically after emacs loads a (tex)-file

Tags: auctex, flyspell

I want to load `flyspell-mode` and execute `flyspell-buffer` automatically after emacs loaded a tex file. I tried the following which loads `flyspell-mode` but doesn't seem to execute `flyspell-buffer`. What would be the proper way to to this? How do I have to change it if I want it on every file not just on LaTeX-files?

```
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "de_DE")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("de_DE" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)
    ("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)
    ))


(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)
```

Comment: I have similar problems, `flyspell` checks for errors but asynchronously (it does not immediately flag errors but only if I scroll to a nearby location). 

Maybe you can try one from the following to see if it helps: `find-file-hooks`, `after-save-hook`, `before-save-hook`, and `auto-save-hook`?

I have the following but it is often very slow: `(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'flyspell-buffer)`.

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas What does the `#` mean in this context?

Comment: @student See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/when-to-sharp-quote-a-lambda-expression

Comment: @student This post explains why is it beneficial to sharp-quote symbols that are functions http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to properly choose and trickily chain hooks.

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook #'flyspell-local-vars)
(defun flyspell-local-vars ()
  (add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook #'flyspell-buffer))
```

- `text-mode-hook`: executed by text major-modes hooks like those of [all TeX variants](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Modes-and-Hooks.html), e.g. `latex-mode-hook`.
- `flyspell-mode-hook`: executed after flyspell minor-mode is loaded, however before local variables have been processed, hence the `flyspell-local-vars` [trick](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocalVariables).
- `hack-local-variables-hook`: [executed after local variables have been processed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html).

`(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook #'flyspell-buffer)` would do the job, but it would use the default dictionary.

Comment: The last `add-hook` should be *local* otherwise `flyspell-buffer` will be run on all buffer you open after opening a text-mode buffer.  IOW it should be `(add-hook 'hack-local-variables #'flyspell-buffer nil 'local)`.