# When should sharp quotes be used?

Tags: elisp, functions, quote, style

I see sharp quotes being used in other people's eLisp code, and I use them myself, but I'm not completely clear on when they are appropriate and when not.

Could anyone clarify on exactly when it's appropriate to use sharp quotes and when ordinary single quotes should be used instead?

Comment: n.b. There are many duplicates for this question here or on S.O.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to sharp-quote a lambda expression?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/when-to-sharp-quote-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3595 is about using `#'` with lambda (where the answer is basically "never"), whereas @izkon's question applies rather to the use of `#'` applied to symbols.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`#'` is just shorthand for `function`, just as `'` is shorthand for `quote`.

You can use it anywhere where you want to indicate to the byte-compiler or the interpreter or a human reader that its argument is expected to be (is treated as) a function.

In many contexts the context determines how the argument is treated if, for example, you simply quote it (use `quote` or `'`) instead of using `#'` (or `function`).  For example, in a context where a symbol is used only for its `symbol-function` property, i.e., it is used as a function, you can just pass the symbol (e.g. by quoting it or passing a variable whose value is the symbol).

But sometimes code is clearer if you do use `#'` in such contexts. Even if Emacs-Lisp itself understands that the symbol is used as a function in such contexts, it might help to emphasize this for a human reader of the code.

In some other Lisps, the treatment of lambda forms that are simply quoted (with `'`) or are unquoted can differ from their use in a function position when quoted using `function` (`#'`). But not in Emacs Lisp. In Emacs Lisp you need not quote (using either `'` or `#'`) a lambda form that you want treated as a function (and not simply as a list). If you do want it handled as just a list, with car `lambda` etc., then quote it (with `'`) -- the example below illustrates this.

From (elisp) [Anonymous Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html):

> -- Special Form: **`function`** `function-object`
>
> This special form returns `FUNCTION-OBJECT` without evaluating it.
>
> In this, it is similar to `quote` (*note Quoting::).  But unlike
>        `quote`, it also serves as a note to the Emacs evaluator and
>        byte-compiler that `FUNCTION-OBJECT` is intended to be used as a
>        function.  Assuming `FUNCTION-OBJECT` is a valid lambda expression,
>        this has two effects:
>
> • When the code is byte-compiled, `FUNCTION-OBJECT` is compiled
>             into a byte-code function object (*note Byte Compilation::).
>
> • When lexical binding is enabled, `FUNCTION-OBJECT` is converted
>             into a closure.  *Note Closures::.
>
> The read syntax `#'` is a short-hand for using `function`.  The
>   following forms are all equivalent:
>
> ```
> (lambda (x) (* x x))
> (function (lambda (x) (* x x)))
> #'(lambda (x) (* x x))
> ```
>
> In the following example, we define a `change-property` function that
>   takes a function as its third argument, followed by a `double-property`
>   function that makes use of `change-property` by passing it an anonymous
>   function:
>
> ```
> (defun change-property (symbol prop function)
>    (let ((value (get symbol prop)))
>      (put symbol prop (funcall function value))))
>
> (defun double-property (symbol prop)
>    (change-property symbol prop (lambda (x) (* 2 x))))
> ```
>
> Note that we do not quote the `lambda` form.
>
> If you compile the above code, the anonymous function is also
>   compiled.  This would not happen if, say, you had constructed the
>   anonymous function by quoting it as a list:
>
> ```
> (defun double-property (symbol prop)
>    (change-property symbol prop '(lambda (x) (* 2 x))))
> ```
>
> In that case, the anonymous function is kept as a lambda expression in
>   the compiled code.  The byte-compiler cannot assume this list is a
>   function, even though it looks like one, since it does not know that
>   `change-property` intends to use it as a function.

Answer (score 13):

`#'` (aka `function`) can be used in front of `(lambda ...)` but it's redundant there, so the only place where it's really meaningful is in front of a symbol, as in `#'car`.  In ELisp, `#'car` and `'car` are almost completely equivalent, so one of the main purpose is simply to document the intention (i.e. to indicate to whoever reads this code that you intend to use this symbol as a function).  Yet there are a few circumstances, where the difference is more significant:

- The byte-compiler takes advantage of this documented intention and when you write `#'car` it will check whether `car` exists as a function, and if it doesn't find it, it will emit a warning, just like it would if you had a call to that function.
- Inside `cl-flet` and `cl-labels`, only `#'f` can refer to the locally 
  defined function `f`, because `'f` will still refer to the global 
  symbol `f` (and whichever function might be stored in its `symbol-function` slot).  E.g.

  ```
  (cl-flet ((car (x y) (+ x y)))
    (list #'car 'car))
  =>
  ((closure nil (x y) (+ x y)) car)
  ```