# defun in defun is not local?

Tags: functions, lexical-scoping, scheme, defun

I am reading SICP to learn Lisp, the book uses Scheme dialect. I want accommodate it to emacs lisp, I find something weird in 3.1.1 and cannot figure it out, say I have a `test.el` file:

```
(defun make-account ()
  (defun withdraw (amount)
    (print "in withdraw"))
  (lambda () 'withdraw))


(setq a (make-account))
(withdraw 10)
```

Execute this file with command `emacs -batch -l test.el` yields `"in withdraw"`. Why is not function `withdraw` local in `make-account`?

And if I comment out `(setq a (make-account))`, it complains about `Symbol’s function definition is void: withdraw`.

What am I missing here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `withdraw` is global, but only declared when `make-account` has been run.

Comment: so how can I define a local function just like `define` in Scheme? then as a returned value which can be called outside?

Comment: Emacs Lisp is *not* Scheme. They're completely different dialects of Lisp, with different idioms. What you'd solve in Scheme by defining a local function is solved in Emacs Lisp by defining another top-level function and using it. For this reason it's common to see functions following the `my--helper-function` or `my-helper-function-1` pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cl-labels` to define local functions (`cl-flet` works, but recursive function reports error), and in the beginning of the `.el` file enable the lexical scoping:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun make-account ()
  (cl-labels ((withdraw (amount)
                        (print "in withdraw")))
    (lambda () #'withdraw)))
```

Remember the `#` before the quoting of function name (for why `#` is needed, see [link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35988/when-should-sharp-quotes-be-used/35991#35991)).

I've tested this in `ielm` mode, the output of `(make-account)` is:

```
ELISP> (make-account)
(closure
 ((--cl-withdraw-- closure #1
                   (amount)
                   (print "in withdraw"))
  t)
 nil --cl-withdraw--)
```

We can see that the closure for `withdraw` is returned.

Thanks to @stefan and @db48x for helpful information.

Comment: "why # is needed" - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35991/5296

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `flet`:

```
(defun make-account ()
  (flet ((withdraw (amount)
                   (print "in withdraw")))
    (lambda () 'withdraw)))
```

Comment: cl.el's `flet` doesn't behave like Common-Lisp's so this won't work.  But if you change that to use `cl-flet` (and then fix the code to use `#'withdraw` and to add a pair of parentheses around `withdraw`'s definition), and tell Aleneuler to use `lexical-binding` then indeed it should work.

Comment: @stefan or db48x: Please consider adding such info to the answer (or another answer). Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.