# What is the difference between these two statements in my init file

Tags: hooks

I'm new to elisp- what is the difference between:

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (flyspell-prog-mode)
          ))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I feel the need to push back on it a bit: Firstly, it seems nonsensical that questions about elisp syntax should not be tagged as `elisp`, secondly the linked page contains no sensible guidance for what beginners _should_ tag their elisp questions as (since its reasonable to assume that beginners do not fully understand the tags the page suggests such as elisp-macros, variables, lexical-scoping). The whole guideline feels a bit gatekeepery.

Comment: The second version is to be preferred. First, because of clarity. Second, you can use `(remove-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)` when needed. If you need more stuff in the hook function, define a named function and add that function via `add-hook`. If the additional stuff is very closely related to `flyspell-prog-mode` then put everything in one named function that you add via one `add-hook` only. If the additional stuff is actually unrelated to `flyspell-prog-mode` use an additional `add-hook`. That helps later on if you want to remove the behavioral modifications separately.

Comment: The point is that if every question that includes a bit of code was tagged `elisp`, then a very large percentage of all the questions would end up with that tag, making it useless as an aid for searching.

Comment: @NickD Fair point in and of itself. That said, there should be an easily discoverable tag such as `elisp-beginners`. As things stand, novices who ask basic/general elisp questions tagged `elisp` are reprimanded, and consequently discouraged from using Emacs. (Luckily I am a thick skinned greybeard )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions added to hooks will be called using `funcall`.

In the first version, you are adding an anonymous function which calls `flyspell-prog-mode` in its body. So when executing the hook function, `funcall` will call the anonymous function which then will call `flyspell-prog-mode`.

In the second version, you are adding a reference to the function `flyspell-prog-mode` directly. So when executing the hook function, `funcall` will call that function directly, i.e. this is the (almost) 'correct' version.

Although it is fine to reference a function via a symbol, it is better to let the compiler know that you are referring to a function by using a sharp quote (see for example [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35988/when-should-sharp-quotes-be-used)), although in this case, as far as I understand, it does not really matter.

Others are welcome to provide more nuanced answers :)

Comment: This and the link you  provided fulfill all the nuancing necessary :-) - IMO. There is one other advantage of `#'` : it tells the *reader* that it's a function - so I always try to use it in such cases, even if not strictly necessary.